# How can I learn more about solving real life problems using multilayer perceptron?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I'm learning about multilayer perceptrons, and looking to tackle some real-world problems in Matlab. Perhaps something like medical diagnosis, or speech recognition... But I'm not really sure where to start here. How should I tackle this?

Comment: What language / platform are you working in?

Comment: I am using Matlab Chris.

Comment: Answers to this question may be of interest, despite not being specific to MLP:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559843/what-problems-have-you-solved-using-artificial-neural-networks/4748513#4748513

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geoff Hinton is the man when it comes to multilayer perceptrons. His Science paper from 2006 used a special class of MLP called an "autoencoder" that was successful in digit recognition, facial recognition, and document classification (all of which have real world applications):
[Reducing the Dimensionality of Data with Neural Networks](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/313/5786/504.full)

Fortunately, they also published the 
[Matlab code](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/MatlabForSciencePaper.html).