# multilayer perceptron matlab code

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I need simple matlab code for prediction 
i want to use multilayer perceptron 
I have 4 input and 1 output

I need code for training the algorithm and other one for test with new data

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  On this site, you're unlikely to get people to just hand you code that does some task unless you've made it clear that you've made some effort to do it yourself.  Otherwise, it looks like you're just asking someone to write code for you, possibly as a way of getting us to do your homework for you.  What have you tried so far?  Where are you getting stuck?  These sorts of questions we can help out with.  The more specific you are about your question, the more likely we are to be able to help.

Answer (score 4):

This is [a previous answer from  @jbrown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939278/how-can-i-learn-more-about-solving-real-life-problems-using-multilayer-perceptro/4975205#4975205):

Geoff Hinton is the man when it comes to multilayer perceptrons. His Science paper from 2006 used a special class of MLP called an "autoencoder" that was successful in digit recognition, facial recognition, and document classification (all of which have real world applications): Reducing the Dimensionality of Data with Neural Networks

[Fortunately, they also published the Matlab code.](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/MatlabForSciencePaper.html)

Also take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939278/examples-of-multilayer-perceptron)

Answer (score 3):

Well....as you are asking for code directly. I don't think that there is someone that will give you the code,but I can give you the direction. If you have access to MATLAB(R), there is nice implementation of MLP and all you have to do is to fill in the blank...

But there is always better one, but I believe that the best one is always the one that you implemented yourself.

GOOD LUCK.

Comment: "...the best one is always the one that you implemented yourself."  I completely agree with this.  One's own code is the one which is best understood, and which is easiest to modify or extend.

Answer (score 0):

"MLP Neural Network with Backpropagation", that is what you are searching for:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/54076-mlp-neural-network-with-backpropagation